# facebookErrDomain code 3000

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, fql.multiquery

Today I received of one of my app users a complaint about an error code 3000.

I could not find any information about this error, nor do I have a clue what caused this error, because i have no tracking in the app. Insights is reporting errors on `fql.multiquery`
I know the queries are fine, only 1 person out of hundreds have this problem at current time.

Did you had this error already or do you know what exactly this error means? As far as I can see there us no official error code list anymore, and copied existing lists do not cover this response code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to get a full error report from facebook:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=3000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 3000.)" UserInfo=0x5e08620 {request_args=(
        {
        key = method;
        value = "fql.multiquery";
    },
        {
        key = sdk;
        value = ios;
    },
        {
        key = queries;
        value = "[...the queries...]";
    },
        {
        key = "sdk_version";
        value = 2;
    },
        {
        key = "access_token";
        value = "...";
    },
        {
        key = format;
        value = json;
    }
), error_msg=Only administrators of applications, pages, and domains can retrieve Insights. The session user (100000XXXXXXXXX) does not own the object 132562XXXXXXXXX., error_code=3000}
```

There was one query accessing the page_fans metric from insights table. The user had only the "Tester" administration privilege associated. Changing the access level of the user to "Administrator" helped.

I changed my error report via UIAlertView to include the "error_msg" from the UserInfo, as it contains important indicators for user and me in case of a failure ;)

The answer for my question is:

**You'll get an facebookErrDomain code 3000 error on graph api in case you do not have proper access rights for page or application insights data.**